# Timer/Counter programming Arduino

Tags: c, atmega328, timers, avr

I'm trying to blink an LED on an ATMega328P (same MCU as Arduino I think..) using the internal timer but I'm stuck since it doesn't seem to light the LED at all....

```
#include <avr/io.h>
//#include <avr/delay.h>

void delay(void);

void delay_long(void);

int main(void) {

  DDRB = 0xFF;                   // port B is configured as output   DDRB : 0b11111111
  DDRB &= ~(1<<PB1);             // pin 1 of port B is configured as input  DDRB : 0b11111101
  PORTB = 0x00;                  // pins of port B are low (output) and with no pull-up resistor (input)
  PORTB |= (1<<PB0)|(1<<PB1);    // pin 0 is high (output) and pin 1 is pulled high (input)    PORTB : 0b00000011

  while(1) {
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0);
    delay();
    PORTB |= 1<<PB0;
    delay();
    PORTB = ~(1<<PB0);
    delay_long();
    PORTB = 1<<PB0;
    delay_long();      
  }

  return 1;

}

void delay(void) {
  TCNT0 = 0x00;
  TCCR0B = 0x05;
  while ( (TIFR0 & TOV0) == 0 ) 
    ;
  TCCR0B = 0x00;
  TIFR0 |= 1<<TOV0;
}

void delay_long(void) {
  TCNT0 = 0x00;
  TCCR0B = 0x05;
  while ( (TIFR0 & TOV0) == 0 ) 
    ;
  TCCR0B = 0x00;
  TIFR0 |= 1<<TOV0;
  TCCR0B = 0x05;
  while ( (TIFR0 & TOV0) == 0 ) 
    ;
  TCCR0B = 0x00;
  TIFR0 |= 1<<TOV0;
}
```

if I remove the body of the event loop it lights up... so I think I must be missing something in the delay functions...

Comment: This looks like an AVR question. You are not using the Arduino core functions (that actually abstract what you are trying to do). In any case you are missing some of the timer configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the offending line is:

```
while ( (TIFR0 & TOV0) == 0 )
```

`TOV0` by itself equals 0, so the above loop will never end.

You should use:

```
 while ( (TIFR0 & (1<<TOV0)) == 0 )
```

instead.